# Setting variables for menu bar in elemnts from controller in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, global-variables, element

I have a element called `top_navigation.ctp` with `Elements` directory. It contains the top menu bar for my website. Now I have a drop down field called `Categories` which contains all the categories the site contains and its dynamic. So in which controller should I set the variables to set the data to the element ?

Answer (score 0):

You should set your categories in beforeFilter() of appController for that because navigation will be included in every page .

```
 function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        ///set your categories here
        $this->set('Categories',$Categories);
    }
```